# How to get a node from xml with all inscope namespaces in root element

Tags: java, xml, element, document, xml-namespaces

Here is my XML file content

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ds=" http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" 
xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2" xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
              <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
               <sac:SignatureInformation>
                  <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                  <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoicesadas</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
                     <ds:SignedInfo>
                         <!-- SOME CONTENT HERE -->
                    </ds:SignedInfo>
                     <ds:SignatureValue></ds:SignatureValue>
                     <ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                           <ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                     </ds:KeyInfo>
                     <ds:Object>
                        <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">
                           <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                              <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                 <xades:SigningTime>2020-12-25T12:57:51Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                 <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    <xades:Cert>
                                       <xades:CertDigest>
                                          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                          <ds:DigestValue> <!-- SOME VALUE HERE --></ds:DigestValue>
                                       </xades:CertDigest>
                                       <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                          <ds:X509IssuerName><!-- SOME VALUE HERE--></ds:X509IssuerName>
                                          <ds:X509SerialNumber><!-- SOME VALUE HERE--></ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                       </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                    </xades:Cert>
                                 </xades:SigningCertificate>
                              </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                           </xades:SignedProperties>
                        </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                     </ds:Object>
                  </ds:Signature>
               </sac:SignatureInformation>
            </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
         </ext:ExtensionContent>
      </ext:UBLExtension>
   </ext:UBLExtensions>
   <!-- SOME CONTENT HERE -->
</Invoice>
```

I want to retrieve the SignedProperties element with all the in scope xmlns namespaces in the file.
Sample Output that i need looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xades:SignedProperties **xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
 xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2" 
xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2"** xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                        <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                            <xades:SigningTime>020-12-25T12:57:51Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                            <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                                <xades:Cert>
                                                    <xades:CertDigest>
                                                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                        <ds:DigestValue> <!-- SOME VALUE HERE --></ds:DigestValue>
                                                    </xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                        <ds:X509IssuerName> <!-- SOME VALUE HERE --></ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                        <ds:X509SerialNumber> <!-- SOME VALUE HERE --></ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                    </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                </xades:Cert>
                                            </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                        </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                    </xades:SignedProperties>
```

But I am getting output without the namespaces defined in the root element in the file.

How should i get the element with all the namespaces declared in scope in the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to apply canonicalization on the extracted xades:SignedProperties node.
You may try to use [Canonicalizer](https://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/c14n/Canonicalizer.html) from Apache Santuario library and canonicalize the extracted node:

```
public static byte[] canonicalizeSubtree(final String canonicalizationMethod, final Node node) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        final Canonicalizer c14n = Canonicalizer.getInstance(getCanonicalizationMethod(canonicalizationMethod));
        c14n.canonicalizeSubtree(node, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

For the canonicalization method, it more looks like an "inclusive" canonicalization, e.g.: "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" (see [ALGO_ID_C14N_WITH_COMMENTS](https://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/c14n/Canonicalizer.html#ALGO_ID_C14N_WITH_COMMENTS)).